# Plot mean in an R plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a mean of valuus to windows in a scatter plot I have. I created the scatter plot with ggplot2

```
 p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) 
p + geom_point()
```

This will give the scatter plot but I woudl like to add add the mean of a window (say size equals 1) and plot this points of the mean as a line. Additionally I woudl like to have vertical bars at each point to indicate the variance.

Mtcars is the data set standard available in ggplot 2

Comment: The mean of what, `wt`? Along which variable?

Comment: the the y-Axis..if you just take windows on the x axis of 1 unit and average all values in that window for their y value

Comment: the variance of a point?

Comment: the variance of the points in a windows

Answer (score 2):

This uses the new dplyr library.

```
library(dplyr)
forLines <- mtcars %.% 
          group_by(cut(wt, breaks = 6)) %.%
          summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg), mean_wt = mean(wt))
p + 
  geom_point(size=5) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut(wt, breaks = 6))) +
  geom_line(data=forLines,aes(x=mean_wt,y=mean_mpg))
```

[image]

Comment: hey...is it still possible to connect the means with a line maybe and then too have th eoriginal point sof the scatter plots to still existi n your plot?

Comment: the problem is just that the originally scatterplot disappears and that there is no line between the means...if that can be done that woudl be really great

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)

s <- seq(0, ceiling(max(mtcars$wt)), 1)
ind <- as.integer(cut(mtcars$wt, s))

myfun <- function(i) 
  c(y = mean(i), ymin = mean(i) - var(i), ymax = mean(i) + var(i))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = myfun, aes(group = ind, x = ind - .5), 
               colour = "red") +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, aes(x = ind - .5), geom = "line",
               colour = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: hey...that looks really good...coudl I ask why your and rmk's solution differ? It shoudl be the same shouldn't it be?

Comment: @user3069326 In the plot by mk, a linear fit is plotted. It is independent of the 1-unit windows.

Comment: as in a linear fit across all the values independent of the values which are derived in several windows but just accross all values?

Comment: @user3069326 Yes, the linear fit is based on all values.

Comment: there is no chance by any means to introduce a shading of the variance area ?

Comment: @user3069326 How do you define *variance area*?

Comment: oh true..just to shade the extrem points of the vertical bars to each other ...so that the vertical bars are shaded between the different points. In principle that there is a shading while you go from mean point to mean  point

Comment: or more simply that just the area is shaded that is embraced by the vertical bars of all variance estimates and the area between the variance bars (splien through the lower and upper limit of variance bar)

Comment: could I also ask how i can adjust the window size in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) 
p + geom_point() + geom_smooth(aes(wt, mpg, group=1), method = "lm")
```

[image]

Comment: hey...that looks really good...coudl I ask why your and Sven's solution differ? It shoudl be the same shouldn't it be?

Comment: As @Sven says in his answer, I guessed that the linear fit was what you were actually `looking` for, although @Sven's answer is what you `asked` for in your question.

Comment: well..does your linear fit take all the y axis values and does a linear regression or does it estimate the mean?

Comment: See: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_smooth.html It has the exact same example as your question.